# The page isn’t redirecting properly for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have hosted a laravel project and gotten this notice [image: The page isn’t redirecting properly]

I am trying to save vendor details into the database and then return dashboard page. It was working fine in localhost but after uploading to a domain it brought this notice. This is what I am using

**vendor.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('vendor.store')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    Name  <br>
    <input type="texSt" name="name" id=""> <br>
    Email  <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id=""> <br>
    Phone Number  <br>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" id=""> <br>
    Town  <br>
    <input type="text" name="town" id=""> <br>
    Location  <br>
    <input type="text" name="location" id=""> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register as a vendor">
</form>
```

**VendorController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $vendor = new Vendor;
    $vendor->user_id = $user_id;
    $vendor->name = $request->name;
    $vendor->email = $request->email;
    $vendor->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
    $vendor->town = $request->town;
    $vendor->location = $request->location;
    $vendor->save();

    return view('dashboard.index');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'ProductController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
Route::resource('role', 'RoleController');
Route::resource('vendor', 'VendorController');
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
Route::get('dashboard/index', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('dashboard/products/show','ProductController@show')->name('show');
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect /vendor http://shop.hotelstore.co.ke/dashboard/index

    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried editing the .htaccess `# Redirect /vendor http://shop.hotelstore.co.ke/dashboard/index` but it did not help. I have tried change the return page but did not work. The vendor data does not go to the database as well. How do I handle this. Help.

Comment: Try `return redirect('dashboard/index');` instead `return view('dashboard.index');`

Comment: redirect() is not working. it bring the same notice

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a folder named `vendor` in your public directory? The reason why you are receiving so many redirects is because you have a route named `vendor` and at the same time, a folder in your public directory also called `vendor` which brings the confusion. You might be required to rename the route.